# Converting warc.gz to .warc

Tags: webarchive, warc

My attempt to extract a warc.gz file, using gzip, resulted in a WARC, but it won't load in http://replayweb.page.

Extracting it using The Unarchiver gave me all the expanded html and other files.

What is the latest recommended method for converting warc.gz to warc? For some reason I am coming up short in my attempts to find suggestions for this simple task.

Thanks!

Comment: .warc.gz is a [supported format](https://replayweb.page/docs/formats) of replayweb.page - is there an error shown when loading the WARC failed?

Answer (score 0):

The programming way is using "[warcio](https://github.com/webrecorder/warcio)" python lib, command-line way is using "warc2warc" utility from [warctools](https://github.com/internetarchive/warctools).

Answer (score 0):

After I tried warc2warc to no success I created the following small python script to accomplish this task.  Seems to work reasonably well!

Usage: `python warcgz-to-warc compressed.warc.gz -o output.warc`

```py
import argparse
import gzip
import shutil
import os

def convert_warc(input_file_path, output_file_path=None):
    if output_file_path is None:
        output_file_path = os.path.splitext(input_file_path)[0]

    with gzip.open(input_file_path, 'rb') as f_in:
        with open(output_file_path, 'wb') as f_out:
            shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Convert a WARC file compressed with gzip to a WARC file.')
    parser.add_argument('input_file_path', help='The path to the input WARC file.')
    parser.add_argument('-o', '--output_file_path', help='The path to the output WARC file. If not provided, the output file will have the same name as the input file with the ".gz" extension removed.')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    convert_warc(args.input_file_path, args.output_file_path)
```